# How to access variables from another SKScene in Swift SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have been having problems with accessing variables from other classes. Here is my code.
This is the class I am trying to access the variable "lastSelection" It is also the first SKScene called to view.

```
class FighterPlaneselect : SKScene {
    var lastSelection:String = ""

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView)  {
        if(true) {
            lastSelection = "Mustang"
        }
    }
}
//Here is the second class called "GameField"
class GameField : SKScene {
    var FighterPlane : FighterPlaneSelect!
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        FighterPlane = FighterPlaneSelect()
        print(FighterPlane.lastSelection)
    }
}
```

Whenever it prints out it prints "". It should be printing "Mustang".

Answer (score 0):

On this line:

`FighterPlane = FighterPlaneSelect()`

You instantiate a **new** SKScene of that class. The problem is, it is never shown so the method: `func didMoveToView(view: SKView)` is never called.

What you need is a reference to the other scene.

One possibility would be to do the following:

```
class FighterPlaneSelect : SKScene {
var lastSelection:String = ""

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView)  {
        if(true) {
            lastSelection = "Mustang"
        }
    }
}

//Here is the second class called "GameField"
class GameField : SKScene {
    var fighterPlane : FighterPlaneSelect!
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        print(FighterPlane.lastSelection)
    }
}

//Here is in the GameScene
let fighterPlaneSelect = FighterPlaneSelect
//show the scene to make it move to view
//then assign the variable inside the gameField object
let gameField = GameField()
gameField.fighterPlane = fighterPlaneSelect
```

Comment: The FighterPlaneSelect view is called first, then the GameField view

Comment: From which class are they called?

Comment: This isn't actually my full code since I don't want to put it out. The FighterPlaneSelect class is the first view ever. It was called GameScene, but I figured out how to change it. So it is the default view

Comment: I cannot help much more without actual code. That said, since your GameScene object holds the reference to the fighterPlaneSelect instantiated object, it can pass it to anyone. If you instantiate your gameField from your GameScene, then you could do what I posted in my revised answer. Essentially, you instantiate your GameField object which holds a variable of type FighterPlaneSelect that is nil. Then you pass that object the reference to your instantiated FighterPlaneSelect object. Hope it makes sense..

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize that variable in scene's init method:

```
  class FighterPlaneselect : SKScene {
    var lastSelection:String = ""

    override  init(size: CGSize){

        super.init(size: size)

         lastSelection = "Mustang"

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView)  {

    }
}
```

And then just use it as you do already:

```
class GameField : SKScene {
    var FighterPlane : FighterPlaneselect!

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {


        FighterPlane = FighterPlaneselect(size: self.size)

        println(FighterPlane.lastSelection)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Very Simple! Just declare lastSelection outside of the class!!

```
class FighterPlaneselect : SKScene {
var lastSelection:String = "" //Declared in the class
}

var lastSelection:String = "" //Declared outside the class
class FighterPlaneselect : SKScene {

}
```